# Completely removing an iOS app from iPhone xS

Tags: ios, applications

I'm trying to delete a few old apps from my iPhone but the best I can do is hide them. Does anyone know of a way to completely and fully delete the apps?  Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to delete them? What do you mean by hide?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When you click and hold the apps in iOS and hit the X, it only deletes them from your screen.  If you go into Apps Store > Updates > Account > Purchased > My Purchases > Not On this iPhone, the apps still appear there and I can only hide them again, not delete them.  They also appear under your AppleID account page under Hidden Apps.  I'd like to remove any evidence that I'd ever downloaded them.

Comment: Ah, understood. That‘s a rather different question though. Please ask a new question for this, making it very clear that you are looking for a way to remove the app from your purchase history.

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the app icon, when the X appears, press it to delete the app.

This doesn’t hide the app, but actually deletes it and all locally stored data from the device. Whether it also deletes any app data stored in a cloud service depends on the app.